# Using getList() to get an object that includes an array of responses

Tags: restangular

My server's REST API responds to a `GET` request for stories with an object like the following:

```
bookmark: "g1AAAAEoeJzLYWBgYMlgTmFQSklKzi9KdUhJMjTQy83PzyvOyMxL1UvOyS9NScwr0ctLLckBqmVKZEiy____fxaY4-a0KbA8-7lHcaJQFsgQRbghRvjMSHIAkkn1qMbEBG0VT-RFM8YMnzF5LECSoQFIAU3ajzCqaMqJzw8SedCMMids1AGIUf-RjTrdMTGRMysLAOQyZD8"
rows: [{id: "IPc3JoAvxHJt426ULI8Qwg", order: [20141108190902.652, 21],…},…]
total_rows: 12
```

I am using Restantular's `getList()` to get stories, along with a custom response interceptor to turn the response object into an array of stories.  My response interceptor looks like this:

```
    RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, responses, deferred) {
      if(operation !== "getList") return data;
      var response = jQuery.map(data.rows, function(row, i){
                        return (row.doc);
                     });
      return response;  
    });
```

Now, however, I find that I need to access the `bookmark` and `total_rows` attributes in the server response.  I know that `getList()` throws an error whenever it is asked to return an object instead of an array.  So I can't simply return something like this in my response interceptor:

```
return { data:data, stories:response }
```

What is the best way to use Restangular to get both the stories list and the additional attributes?

Comment: use customGET instead of getList. customGET will allow you to have object instead of collection. getList requires a collection in response. If you response contains object, and in that you have your array and other things, then you should use customGET method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the responseInterceptor that I'm now using to solve this problem:

```
    RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, responses, deferred) {

       if(operation !== "getList") return data;

       var response;

       response = jQuery.map(data.rows, function(row, i){
                     return (row.doc);
                  });
       response.meta = { total_rows: data.total_rows, bookmark: data.bookmark };

       return response; 

});
```